# Google Calendar Mobile Version - embed

Tags: iphone, mobile, uiwebview, google-calendar-api

I want to embed a google calendar into an iphone app, my webview is fine, except I can't seem to get the URL I need to view the mobile version without having to logging in.

I know its possible as this is done in the twit app (See Screenshot below).

How can I do this?

Lets say the public google calendar is [link text](http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=northadelaidefitness%40gmail.com&color=%230D7813&ctz=Australia%2FAdelaide) and I want to view the **Mobile** version of this page in a UIView.

The mobile view is available at [link text](http://www.google.com/calendar/gp?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=northadelaidefitness%40gmail.com&color=%230D7813&ctz=Australia%2FAdelaide), but you must first be logged into a google account.

Help Stackoverflow!

[alt text http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/norskben/RtIkoblEW9VsBE07dAQy9Sjjo4aRL2yjCRTCIx316y7ovsCXo9iKeGLL1AMx/photo.jpg](http://posterous.com/getfile/files.posterous.com/norskben/RtIkoblEW9VsBE07dAQy9Sjjo4aRL2yjCRTCIx316y7ovsCXo9iKeGLL1AMx/photo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All under control now. Although I didn't find it possible to access the gp mobile view, it turned out infact to be just the agenda view of the normal view.

```
NSString *gcal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320\"/><iframe src=\"http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=2&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;src=northadelaidefitness@gmail.com&amp;color=%23A32929&amp;ctz=Australia%2FAdelaide\" style=\"border-width: 0pt;\" mce_style=\" border-width:0 \" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"400\" width=\"300\"></iframe>"];

[webview loadHTMLString:gcal baseURL:nil];   //load above html string (notice the viewport=320 for iphone resizing
webview.delegate = self; //add delegate for activity access
webview.scalesPageToFit =YES; //scale nicely
```

Comment: How can we get Event Color from iphone-gcal-example ?